# Uber Details On sandbox

Tags: uber-api

I am using uber-api`s in India for my project,as my project is still in the development phase,i am using  the sandbox environment.While using this testing environment uber is just returning the following details on the sandbox environment
1.Allows to book a ride.
2.List of the products of the uber(Uberx,UberGo)
3.Dummy receipt.

The information that is missing on the sandbox environment is
1.The Driver Details
2.Vehicle Details
3.Surge Pricing.

Is there any way through which i can get all these details on my sandbox environment?or is it a bug?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sandbox mode](https://developer.uber.com.cn/docs/sandbox) passes through calls to all available endpoints. It essentially makes exceptions for **/requests/{request_id}** and **/products/{product_id}** (by allowing you to use HTTP PUT):

> At this time, most of the endpoints in the Sandbox environment are proxied straight to the production environment. The Request endpoint is the primary exception. It allows you to exercise the flow of ordering an Uber in your application without worrying about a real world trip being created. Additionally, you can simulate surging products or no drivers being available to ensure that your application handles these scenarios properly.

I have to admit that I'm not familiar with India-specific differences for the Uber API (would love to know them), but in general, the Uber API allows you to do this:

1) **[GET /requests/current](https://developer.uber.com.cn/docs/v1-requests-current)** and **[GET /requests/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com.cn/docs/v1-requests-details)**: Returns (amongst other elements) the driver & vehicle details as JSON objects:

`{ 
   ...
   "driver": {
      "phone_number": "(555)555-5555",
      "rating": 5,
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/img.jpeg",
      "name": "Bob"
   },
   "vehicle":{
      "make": "Bugatti",
      "model": "Veyron",
      "license_plate": "I<3Uber",
      "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/car.jpeg"
   },
   ...
}`

2) **[POST /requests](https://developer.uber.com.cn/docs/v1-requests)**: When booking a ride, the server can return a HTTP 409 status code - in case surge pricing is in effect. It provides the following details in a JSON object:

`"meta": {
   "surge_confirmation": {
      "href": "https:\/\/api.uber.com\/v1\/surge-confirmations\/e100a670",
      "surge_confirmation_id": "e100a670",
      "multiplier": 1.4,
      "expires_at": 1459191276
   }
}`

To complete, you would need to redirect the user to the confirmation URL (`meta.surge_confirmation.href`)